# Resize High Charts based on grid layout width and height using react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a wrote a grid layout component in react. Inside the grid, I have loaded the high chart and it works great.  On resizing the width and height of the grid, the high chart doesn't resize and it breaks when resizing.
I have searched for stack overflow and found the same question in here "[Resize highcharts using react-grid-layout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430415/resize-highcharts-using-react-grid-layout-not-working)". Then i came to know that `chart reflow` method is to be called to make the high chart fit with in the grid when the grid layout changes. Since i am new to react, I don't know how to make it possible. Help me with some solutions.

Here's the code i tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import '/home/paulsteven/Documents/resize-ui/resize_ui/node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import '/home/paulsteven/Documents/resize-ui/resize_ui/node_modules/react-resizable/css/styles.css';
import GridLayout from 'react-grid-layout';
import BarChart from "highcharts-react-official";


class MyFirstGrid extends React.Component {
  state ={
    options :{reflow:true,
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Steven Chart'
            },
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Prince',
            data: [4, 4, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Syed',
            data: [5, 3, 5]
        },
        {
            name: 'Sam',
            data: [1, 3, 3]
        }]
      }
    }

  render() {
    // layout is an array of objects, see the demo for more complete usage
    var layout = [
      {i: 'a', x: 0, y: 0, w: 5, h: 2},
      {i: 'b', x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2},
      {i: 'c', x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2}
    ];
    return (
      <GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>
        <div style={{backgroundColor: 'grey'}}  key="a">

                  {/* <div id="container" style={{width:'100%',height:'400px'}}></div> */}

                  <BarChart options ={this.state.options} />
        </div>
        <div  style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}key="b">b</div>
        <div style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}} key="c">c</div>
      </GridLayout>
    )
  }
}

export default MyFirstGrid;
```

Comment: Hi @smackbeta, That is a bug in Highcharts, which is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9491. I reproduced your code in online code editor and it seems that calling `chart.reflow()` method is not enough. Please check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-fnj1i with disabled `reflow` and please let me know if this meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I tried your example and changed the `chat overflow` to `true` to check whether the chat gets reflow when the grid layout changed. But it fails. The chart gets breaked. I want the chart to be resized as per the grid layout size.

Comment: @ppotaczek, is there any other way to make it possible....

Comment: Hi @smackbeta, Please check this similar thread with `antd`: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/121. The solution was to set `hasSider` property, is there something similar in `react-grid-layout`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason why the functionality of resizing highchrts is not working you can find it from [the documentation of 'reflow' from hightcharts](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart?&_ga=2.190944041.2091026978.1615450514-419751775.1614851717#reflow)

> By default, the chart reflows automatically to its container following a window.resize event, as per the chart.reflow option. However, there are no reliable events for div resize, so if the container is resized without a window resize event, this must be called explicitly.

The situation matches what you did now: you tried to resize the div itself but not the window size, so it doesn't work as you expected.

What I did to make my charts resizable in grid as following:

1. Create a function to do reflow

```js
const onLayoutChange = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i += 1) {
      if (Highcharts.charts[i] !== undefined) {
        Highcharts.charts[i].reflow(); // here is the magic to update charts' looking
      }
    }
  };
```

2. Use `onLayoutChange` provided by `react-grid-layout`

```html
<GridLayout
    cols={12}
    layout={layout}
    rowHeight={30}
    width={1200}
    onLayoutChange={() => onLayoutChange()}
>
...
</GridLayout>
```

And then...BANG! you got resizable charts controlled by the resize button in `react-grid-layout`.

Make it easy to understand, you can view live working here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/resize-highcharts-in-grid-9e625?file=/src/App.js

Comment: your code working fine for width but height is not responsive

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Solution to make it fit in the grid layout:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import '/node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import '/node_modules/react-resizable/css/styles.css';
import GridLayout from 'react-grid-layout';
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

const options = {
  series: [
    {
      data: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  ]
};

class MyFirstGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.conRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    // layout is an array of objects, see the demo for more complete usage
    var layout = [
      { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 5, h: 5 },
      { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2 },
      { i: "c", x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 }
    ];
    return (
      <GridLayout
        className="layout"
        layout={layout}
        cols={12}
        rowHeight={30}
        width={1200}
        onResizeStop={function(event) {

         this.myRef.current.chart.setSize(this.conRef.current.clientWidth,this.conRef.current.clientHeight)
          console.log('hello', event);
        }.bind(this)}
      >
        <div ref={this.conRef}  style={{ backgroundColor: "#00000000" }} key="a">
          <HighchartsReact
            ref= {this.myRef}
            containerProps={{ style: { width: '100%', height: '100%' } }}
            options={options}
            highcharts={Highcharts}
          />
        </div>

        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} key="b">
          b
        </div>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }} key="c">
          c
        </div>
      </GridLayout>
    );
  }
}


export default MyFirstGrid;
```